# salesforce custom button

Tags: javascript

I have Custom button name as "Create reservation" where i execute javascript. 
Which is on "Property Object" When custom picklist field value equals to "Available" then it should redirect to another page otherwise no action perform from "Create reservation" button.
How to do it? actually m newbie in salesforce.
Here my OnClick JavaScript-

```
window.open('/apex/Create_Reservation?kk={!Property__c.Id}','_blank');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check the value in javascript. Something like

```
If('{!custom_picklist}' == 'Available')
    window.open('/apex/Create_Reservation?kk={!Property__c.Id}','_blank');
```

try this. it will solve your problem.

Comment: it gives error-  salesforce a problem with the onclick javascript for this button or link was encountered

Comment: @user24524 can you share your code.

Comment: @user24524 i am happy that it solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It's Working-

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/Create_Reservation")}

var prop = "Available";
var propStage= '{!Property__c.Status__c}';
if (propStage!=prop)
{
alert("Please note - You can only create a reservation on available property.");
}
else {

window.open('/apex/Create_Reservation?kk={!Property__c.Id}','_blank');
}
```